# Phonegap: when does the deviceready listener fire?

Tags: cordova

Is it when the app is loaded? What if you leave the app, the javascript stops executing, and then return and the javascript starts running again - is it fired again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is only fired when the application starts up and PhoneGap is loaded. If you leave the app a pause event will be fired. When you come back to the app a resume event will be fired.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#Events

Comment: that was the api article i needed. i wish i'd seen it earlier.  thanks!